# ubuntu jammy ISO not respect preseed file for automation anymore?

Tags: preseed

I build ubuntu 18.04/20.04 customize ISO and update the ubuntu.seed file with cubic ( https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic )

but when I try to do the same procedure with ubuntu jammy , the ISO didn't respect the preseed file, I don't know why and have no related log file to determine what's going on.

Can anybody confirm that ubuntu jammy didn't follow the preseed file ? and if so , is there any other solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and that [happened](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/server-installer-plans-for-20-04-lts/13631) with 20.04. From the link:

> With 20.04 LTS, we will be completing the transition to the live server installer and discontinuing the classic server installer based on debian-installer (d-i), allowing us to focus our engineering efforts on a single codebase. The next-generation subiquity server installer brings the comfortable live session and speedy install of Ubuntu Desktop to server users.
>
> If you have use cases for which you rely on d-i and that are not addressed by subiquity today, please let us know, by early January, what those are so we can incorporate that feedback into our plans for the 20.04 LTS development cycle.

We now use [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) and `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` can be used as a template. Interesting parts in the link (besides the examples):

> Quick start
>
> So you just want to try it out? Well we have the [page](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart) for you.
>
> Creating an autoinstall config
>
> When any system is installed using the server installer, an autoinstall file for repeating the install is created at `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data`.